# EF Grandchildren Single Row

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata

I have a relation that has grandchildren

```
public class School {
  [Key]
  public int SchoolId {get; set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public virtual ICollection<Room> {get;set;}
}

public class Room {
  [Key]
  public int RoomId {get;set;}
  public string Number {get;set;}
  public int SchoolId {get;set;}
  [ForeignKey("SchoolId")]
  public virtual School School {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<Person> People {get;set;}
}

public class Person {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int RoomId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("RoomId")]
    public virtual Room Room {get;set;}
}
```

I'm trying to load all records of room but I only get one room even though a school will have more than one.  I'm returning an IQueryable for School back and allowing oData to make the query for Room and Person through Entity Framework 6. I only get 1 record back for Person when there is more than one.  When I run the SQL generated I see all of the people that should be included but I don't see them in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I see what was happening in this case I did mask the actual table and field names in my example to keep the project under wraps.  It had to do with saying a non primary key was the key and leaving the primary key off of the class.  I corrected that and all the records started showing.  I guess EF will only show the first records of the unique keys of a table?